# SharePoint 2013 - User Profile Photo's Image Rendition

Tags: user-profile, mysite, mysites, image-rendition

Is it possible to activate image rendition on the MySites Host Collection?  I need to be able to allow users to edit (crop etc.) their profile photos upon upload.  Is image rendition applicable to MySites?  Will I need a third party tool instead to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure you can do it with Mysite, You can enable it using the hacking the url.

1. Enable the BlobCache on Mysite
2. then go this url "`www.mysite.com/_layouts/15/ImageRenditionSettings.aspx`" and create item here.

But i am not sure will it work, But another thing Bydefault Profile picture having three sizes when people upload the picture.

Read more here:

[SharePoint 2013: User Profile Photo Sizes](https://spsawyer.wordpress.com/2013/07/31/sharepoint-2013-user-profile-photo-sizes/)

[Image Renditions in SharePoint 2013](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/image-renditions-sharepoint-2013/)